# Persist in memory not working in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, persist

I am trying the persist feature in Spark to persist the data in memory and do computations on it. I am under the assumption that storing the data in memory would make the computations faster for iterative algorithms such as K-means clustering in MLlib.

```
    val data3 = sc.textFile("hdfs:.../inputData.txt")
    val parsedData3 = data3.map( _.split('\t').map(_.toDouble))
    parsedData3.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
```

The call to persist throws the following error:

```
    scala> parsedData3.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
    <console>:17: error: not found: value MEMORY_ONLY
                  parsedData3.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
```

Could someone help me with how to correctly use persist to save a data in memory for use in an iterative algorithm?

Comment: `error: not found: value MEMORY_ONLY` - did you actually read this?! ;)

Comment: realize this is not a Java question for for the Java folks reading this, don't forget to put the parenthesis on the end: StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER() and use import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `rdd.persist` being: `def persist(newLevel: StorageLevel): this.type`  you can see that it takes a value of type 'StorageLevel', so the correct way to call persist in your example would be:

```
parsedData3.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
```

The companion object of [StorageLevel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel$)  defines these constants, so bringing it into context will allow you to use the constant directly (as in your code)

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel._
...
parsedData3.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)  // this also works
```

Comment: or `parsedData3.persist()` since `MEMORY_ONLY` is the default

Comment: `MEMORY_ONLY` is not the default anymore as of spark 2.3.1